# apache nifi- how to create a custom date format

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am new to nifi and I am trying to create a week_start_date and week_number from the date in json format.

I am using jolt transform.

The input is google ads api response.

This is the spec I use:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "customer_id": {
        "*": "[&].customer_id"
      },
      "customer_name": {
        "*": "[&].customer_name"
      },
      "account_currency_code": {
        "*": "[&].account_currency_code"
      },
      "campaign_id": {
        "*": "[&].campaign_id"
      },
      "campaign_name": {
        "*": "[&].campaign_name"
      },
      "campaign_status": {
        "*": "[&].campaign_status"
      },
      "ad_group_id": {
        "*": "[&].ad_group_id"
      },
      "ad_group_name": {
        "*": "[&].ad_group_name"
      },
      "clicks": {
        "*": "[&].clicks"
      },
      "cost": {
        "*": "[&].cost"
      },
      "impressions": {
        "*": "[&].impressions"
      },
      "device": {
        "*": "[&].device"
      },
      "date": {
        "*": "[&].date"
      },
      "week_number": {
        "*": "[&].week_number"
      },
      "year": {
        "*": "[&].year"
      },
      "keywords": {
        "*": "[&].keywords"
      },
      "keywords_id": {
        "*": "[&].keywords_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "date": {
        "date": "=intSubtract(@(1,date))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output should be:

```json
[
  {
    "customer_id": "2538943578",
    "customer_name": "test.com",
    "account_currency_code": "USD",
    "campaign_id": "11137311251",
    "campaign_name": "testers",
    "campaign_status": "ENABLED",
    "ad_group_id": "1111",
    "ad_group_name": "tesst- E",
    "clicks": "6",
    "cost": "26580000",
    "impressions": "40",
    "device": "DESKTOP",
    "date": "2021-12-01",
    "week_number": "48",
    "week_start_date": "2021-11-29",
    "year": 2021,
    "keywords": "test",
    "keywords_id": "56357925842"
  }
]
```

the output I have:

```json
[
  {
    "customer_id": "2538943578",
    "customer_name": "test.com",
    "account_currency_code": "USD",
    "campaign_id": "11137311251",
    "campaign_name": "testers",
    "campaign_status": "ENABLED",
    "ad_group_id": "1111",
    "ad_group_name": "tesst- E",
    "clicks": "6",
    "cost": "26580000",
    "impressions": "40",
    "device": "DESKTOP",
    "date": "2021-12-01",
    "week_number": "2021-11-29",
    "year": 2021,
    "keywords": "test",
    "keywords_id": "56357925842"
  }
]
```

I am not sure on how to use correctly the modify-default-beta

Also I tried looking at the docs:
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/tree/master/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/shiftr

What is the correct way also to understand the structure?

Comment: Btw, can you add the current input ?

Comment: I added a comment about the input

Comment: Unfortunately Jolt doesn't have a date conversion utility, and some workarounds in order to compute week number would be tricky  I think

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did see some way to add a filed inside the json using
"modify-default-beta"

Comment: Shame it couldn`t be done